# Redirect https to http on mobile devices

Tags: http, mobile, https

How would i redirect HTTPS requests to HTTP on mobile devices?
The SSL certificate for my website doesn't work on mobile devices, i get a security warning.

I already use

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

on my website...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Im about to ask it again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done. Suppose your mobile site is m.example.org. When a mobile user connects to https://m.example.org, the user gets a certificate warning. That warning is shown and the TLS connection is closed before the browser can see your HTTP reply. So you cannot use 301 to redirect in this case.

Comment: It doesn't use https://m.example.org, it's http://www.example.org. Just like the site on pc..